# How to save (cvWrite or imwrite) an image in OpenCV 2.4.3?

Tags: opencv, face-detection, save-image

I am trying to save an OpenCV image to the hard drive.

Here is what I tried:

```
public void SaveImage (Mat mat) {
  Mat mIntermediateMat = new Mat();

  Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);

  File path =
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
  String filename = "barry.png";
  File file = new File(path, filename);

  Boolean bool = null;
  filename = file.toString();
  bool = Highgui.imwrite(filename, mIntermediateMat);

  if (bool == true)
    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS writing image to external storage");
    else
    Log.d(TAG, "Fail writing image to external storage");
  }
}
```

Can any one show how to save that image with OpenCV 2.4.3?

Comment: Most probably you need to add sdcard access permissions to your manifest.

Comment: I am not doing this on Android phone.I just got the above sample from Another trend asking the question i am asking for Android phone.What i just want to do is, to save a cropped face from a face detection code as a new image using a function just like the above one but using IplImage* on desktop not Android.Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Highgui is replaced with Imgcodecs from version 3. mRgba is actually the input mat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059576/highgui-path-is-missing-in-opencv-3-0-0-generated-jar-classnotfoundexception-or

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, as your question is concerning OpenCV on the desktop, but your code is for Android, and you ask about IplImage, but your posted code is using C++ and Mat. Assuming you're on the desktop using C++, you can do something along the lines of:

```
cv::Mat image;
std::string image_path;
//load/generate your image and set your output file path/name
//...

//write your Mat to disk as an image
cv::imwrite(image_path, image);
```

...Or for a more complete example:

```
void SaveImage(cv::Mat mat)
{
    cv::Mat img;     
    cv::cvtColor(...); //not sure where the variables in your example come from
    std::string store_path("..."); //put your output path here       

    bool write_success = cv::imwrite(store_path, img);
    //do your logging... 
}
```

The image format is chosen based on the supplied filename, e.g. if your `store_path` string was "output_image.png", then imwrite would save it was a PNG image. You can see the list of valid extensions at [the OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#Mat%20imread%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29).

One caveat to be aware of when writing images to disk with OpenCV is that the scaling will differ depending on the Mat type; that is, for floats the images are expected to be within the range [0, 1], while for say, unsigned chars they'll be from [0, 256).

For IplImages, I'd advise just switching to use Mat, as the old C-interface is deprecated. You can convert an IplImage to a Mat via `cvarrToMat` then use the Mat, e.g.

```
IplImage* oldC0 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320,240),16,1);
Mat newC = cvarrToMat(oldC0);
//now can use cv::imwrite with newC
```

alternately, you can convert an IplImage to a Mat just with

```
Mat newC(oldC0); //where newC is a Mat and oldC0 is your IplImage
```

Also I just noticed [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html) at the OpenCV website, which gives you a walk-though on loading and saving images in a (desktop) environment.

Comment: Thank you so much.This is all i want and you have answered my question.I am working on Face Recognition and as openCv 2.4.3 has a Face Recognizer API unlike the openCV version 2.3.x.Changing an IplImage* in to cv::Mat format and saving the image as a mat will make my life easier.Since the FaceRecognizer API uses cv::Mat input.Thanks alot alrikai.

Comment: glad to hear it helped! I'd also advise reading over the OpenCV documentation at their site (http://opencv.org/documentation.html), they have a lot of good information to get you going