# HighGUI is missing from OpenCV 3.0.0 JAR

Tags: java, c++, opencv, clojure

I was compiling OpenCV 3.0.0 with Java support. My script was:

```
mkdir /opt/opencv /opt/opencv/opencv-build
cd /opt/opencv
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git 
cd /opt/opencv/opencv-build
export OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/opencv
export FFMPEG_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH/lib:$FFMPEG_PATH:/opt/opencv/opencv/3rdparty/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig
cmake28 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/opencv" \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_C_FLAGS="-DHAVE_CAMV4L -DHAVE_CAMV4L2" \
        -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ../opencv
make
make install
```

as told in http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html with `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`.

And when I wanted to test installation I found out that there is no Highgui class and no path for it. Here are my `opencv-300.jar` `org.opencv` folder contents:

```
calib3d
core
features2d
imgcodecs
imgproc
ml
objdetect
photo
utils
video
videoio
```

Have I missed something during installation?

Comment: OpenCV 3.0.0 is not yet a stable version, it is probably something because it is still in dev mode

Comment: highgui was split up into videoio,imcdodecs and highgui. it's not included in the jar, since there *is* no gui functionality for java

Comment: @berak yes, you are right.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Short Answer : There is no more `HighGUI` module in Java for 3.0 anymore.

Long One : The functionality in `HighGUI` has been split into two additional modules:

1. videoio (VideoCapture, VideoWriter).
2. imgcodecs (imread/imwrite and friends).

Since there's no GUI functionality exposed to Java, there is no need to have a HighGUI module in Java anymore.

Comment: OLD CODE: Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);

NEW CODE: Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);

Answer (score 73):

**Migrating from OpenCV 2.x to 3.0.0 (Java)**

```
Highgui.imread(fileName, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
Highgui.imread(fileName)
```

become resp:

```
Imgcodecs.imread(fileName, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
Imgcodecs.imread(fileName)
```

Also, drawing functions such as:

```
Core.circle(..), Core.line(..), etc..
```

Have been moved to:

```
Imgproc.circle(..), Imgproc.line(..)
```

Note
Moments, HuMoments missing in 3.0.0. Will be fixed in 3.1
See [bug](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5017)

Comment: Nice, thanks for adding additional changes required.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of trouble !

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I found at the end of introduction http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/clojure_dev_intro/clojure_dev_intro.html answer for my question:

> The OpenCV Java API does not wrap the highgui module functionalities
>   depending on Qt (e.g. namedWindow and imshow. If you want to create
>   windows and show images into them while interacting with OpenCV from
>   the REPL, at the moment you’re left at your own. You could use Java
>   Swing to fill the gap.