# Convert OpenCV Mat object to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, opencv, bufferedimage

I am trying to create a helper function using OpenCV Java API that would process an input image and return the output byte array. The input image is a jpg file saved in the computer. The input and output image are displayed in the Java UI using Swing.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
// Load image from file
Mat rgba = Highgui.imread(filePath);

Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);

// Convert back to byte[] and return
byte[] return_buff = new byte[(int) (rgba.total() * rgba.channels())];
rgba.get(0, 0, return_buff);
return return_buff;
```

When the `return_buff` is returned and converted to BufferedImage I get NULL back. When I comment out the `Imgproc.cvtColor` function, the `return_buff` is properly converted to a BufferedImage that I can display. It seems like the `Imgproc.cvtColor` is returning a Mat object that I couldn't display in Java.

Here's my code to convert from byte[] to BufferedImage:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputByteArray);
BufferedImage outputImage = ImageIO.read(in);
```

In above code, outputImage is NULL

Does anybody have any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ImageIO.read(...)` (and the `javax.imageio` package in general) is for reading/writing images from/to file formats. What you have is an array containing "raw" pixels. It's impossible for `ImageIO` to determine file format from this byte array. Because of this, it will return `null`.

Instead, you should create a `BufferedImage` from the bytes directly. I don't know OpenCV that well, but I'm assuming that the result of `Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0)` will be an image in grayscale (8 bits/sample, 1 sample/pixel). This is the same format as [`BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_GRAY). If this assumption is correct, you should be able to do:

```
// Read image to Mat as before
Mat rgba = ...;
Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);

// Create an empty image in matching format
BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(rgba.width(), rgba.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

// Get the BufferedImage's backing array and copy the pixels directly into it
byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) gray.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
rgba.get(0, 0, data);
```

Doing it this way, saves you one large byte array allocation and one byte array copy as a bonus. :-)

Comment: This answer is outdated. Since version 3.0, there is no more Highgui module on openCV. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059576/highgui-is-missing-from-opencv-3-0-0-jar

Comment: @Prometheus Updated answer. The question is about conversion from `Mat` to `BufferedImage` though, not about how to read images using OpenCV, so I simply removed the reference to `HighGUI`.

Answer (score 9):

I used this kind of code to convert Mat object to Buffered Image.

```
static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat matrix)throws Exception {        
    MatOfByte mob=new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", matrix, mob);
    byte ba[]=mob.toArray();

    BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba));
    return bi;
}
```