# When using OpenCV-3.1.0, what is the method to get the functionality of "Highgui.imencode()" provided in OpenCV-2x?

Tags: java, opencv

I have installed OpenCV-3.1.0 and in 3.0.0 or later versions, there's no HighGUI module in Java. That functionality is split in to two additional modules (videoio,imgcodecs).

I'm trying to capture a video from web cam using Java with OpenCv. Here's a class I found that does the Job. But since my version is not having HighGUI module, what is the way (or the code) that I can use to get the same functionality, instead of "Highgui.imencode()"?

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

/**
 * @author erandi
 */
public class WebCamTesting extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form WebCamTesting
     */

    //definitions
    private DaemonThread myThread = null;
    int count = 0;
    VideoCapture webSource = null;

    Mat frame = new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();

    //class of thread
    class DaemonThread implements Runnable {
        protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (runnable) {
                    if (webSource.grab()) {
                        try {
                            webSource.retrieve(frame);

                            //Error - can't find the class Highgui
                            Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);

                            Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

                            BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                            Graphics g = jPanelVideo.getGraphics();

                            if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() - 150, 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null))

                                if (runnable == false) {
                                    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                                    this.wait();
                                }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public WebCamTesting() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanelVideo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButtonStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonPause = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelVideoLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelVideo);
        jPanelVideo.setLayout(jPanelVideoLayout);
        jPanelVideoLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanelVideoLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGap(0, 454, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanelVideoLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanelVideoLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGap(0, 335, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButtonStart.setText("Start");
        jButtonStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonStartActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButtonPause.setText("Pause");
        jButtonPause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonPauseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(121, 121, 121)
                                .addComponent(jButtonStart)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButtonPause)
                                .addGap(117, 117, 117))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                                .addComponent(jPanelVideo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jPanelVideo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jButtonPause)
                                        .addComponent(jButtonStart))
                                .addGap(55, 55, 55))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        webSource = new VideoCapture(0);    //video capture from default cam
        myThread = new DaemonThread();     //create object from thread class
        Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.runnable = true;
        t.start();                      //start thread

        jButtonStart.setEnabled(false);  //deactivate start button
        jButtonPause.setEnabled(true);  // activate pause button
    }

    private void jButtonPauseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        myThread.runnable = false;      //stop thread
        jButtonPause.setEnabled(false); //activate start
        jButtonStart.setEnabled(true);  //deactivate pause

        webSource.release();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); // load native library of opencv
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new WebCamTesting().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonPause;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonStart;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelVideo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HighGUI is missing from OpenCV 3.0.0 JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059576/highgui-is-missing-from-opencv-3-0-0-jar)

Comment: I know that the HighGUI missing in 3.0.0 or later versions and now it's functionality is split in to two additional modules. But I need the exact method that I can use to get the functionality of "Highgui.imencode()".

Comment: Imgcodecs.imencode()

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll proceed

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", image, bytemat);
```