# How can I crop Detected Face from the Video Streaming and store it in a folder using OpenCV Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, face-detection

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9, Java language and eclipse. My Face Detection code is given below. The question is how can I crop out the detected face and store it in a folder?

I've trying hard for it but couldn't get the required output.

```
package code03;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class VideoPanel2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //***********************************************************************************************
    private BufferedImage image;
    int count = 1;
    //***********************************************************************************************
    public VideoPanel2()
    {
        super();
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    public BufferedImage getimage()
    {
        return image;
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    public void setimage(BufferedImage newimage)
    {
        image = newimage;
        return;
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);   
        if (this.image==null) return;         
         g.drawImage(this.image,10,492,650,43,this.image.getWidth(),this.image.getHeight(), count, count, null);
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************

    public void DatainIt() throws Exception{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Face Detection");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,800);

        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java249");
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("./res/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        //CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("./res/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        VideoPanel2 vidPanel = new VideoPanel2();
        frame.setContentPane(vidPanel);

        //BUTTON
        JButton save = new JButton("Add a new Person");
        //save.setBounds(2, 2, 30, 80);
        JPanel pbutton = new JPanel();
        pbutton.add(save);
        //TextField
        JTextField p_name = new JTextField(25);
        frame.add(p_name);
        frame.add(pbutton);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        save.addActionListener(this);

        Mat webcam_image = new Mat();
        MatToBufImg mat2Buf = new MatToBufImg();

        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
        if(capture.isOpened())
        {
            Thread .sleep(100); //Give time to webcam to initialize itself
            while(true)
            {
                capture.read(webcam_image);
                if(!webcam_image.empty())
                {
                    frame.setSize(webcam_image.width()+40, webcam_image.height()+60);
                    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
                    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(webcam_image, faceDetections);
                    for(Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
                    {
                        Core.rectangle(webcam_image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255,0));
                        //Mat croppedImage = setimage(rect);

                    }
                    mat2Buf.setMatrix(webcam_image, ".jpg");

                    //Highgui.imwrite("webcam_image.jpg", faceDetections);
                    //File file = new File("Image" + "." + ".jpg");
                    //ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) webcam_image, ".jpg", file);
                    vidPanel.setimage(mat2Buf.getBufferedImage());
                    vidPanel.repaint();

                    // get the video stream
                    //BufferedImage bi = mat2Buf.getBufferedImage();//getimage();
                    //bi.getSubimage(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                    //File outputfile= new File("D:\\Java Project\\FaceRecognition\\src\\code03\\Face Database\\saved.jpg");
                    //ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) bi, "jpg", outputfile);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Problems with WebCam Capture");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//end if
        capture.release();
    }//end DatainIt()
    //***********************************************************************************************
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception{
        VideoPanel2 vid = new VideoPanel2();
        vid.DatainIt();
    }//end main
    //***********************************************************************************************   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }

}//end of class
```

The code of other file used in this class is:

```
package code03;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class MatToBufImg{
    Mat matrix;
    MatOfByte mob;
    String fileExten;
public MatToBufImg(){

}

public MatToBufImg(Mat amatrix, String fileExt){
    matrix = amatrix;
    fileExten = fileExt;
}
public void setMatrix(Mat amatrix, String fileExt){
    matrix = amatrix;
    fileExten = fileExt;
    mob = new MatOfByte();
}
public BufferedImage getBufferedImage(){
    Highgui.imencode(fileExten, matrix, mob);
    byte[] byteArray = mob.toArray();
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;
    try{
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bufImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are detecting Face rectangles as MatOfRect and drawing a rectangle on the video.

```
Core.rectangle(webcam_image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255,0));
```

Here, you already have the roi of the image you need. So crop the roi part of the frame as:

```
Mat faceROI = new Mat(webcam_image,rect);
Highgui.imwrite("Face_frameNumber_faceInImageNumber.jpeg", faceROI);
```

Also, please consider moving to Opencv 3.1/latest version. You will benefit from the new features such as optimisations and many algorithms which have been contributed over past year.

**OPENCV 3 onwards**:

Highgui is now broken to VideoIO and ImgCodecs. Also, Core.rectangle like functions has moved to ImgProc.

Comment: Note that code will need to change as a result of Highgui being removed in OpenCV 3.0 and above. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059576/highgui-is-missing-from-opencv-3-0-0-jar) for help.

Comment: @EdwardShen: Yes. Updating my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mee: Are you aware that you get blocked for posting bad questions as well? Please see how you asked this question, where I am commenting. Notice how the code is much indented and comparatively readable. Next, as Lukas in your original/nowDeleted question page said, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Try posting a minimal code. If you are using git(any other VCS), deleting few lines won't matter. Start removing code like setTitle, etc. and you just might find the problem before even asking it.

Comment: Sorry If its offended you.. Actually my post wasn't good enough to fulfill all the requirements of asking a question.. That's why I've deleted it...

Comment: @Mee Not offended at all. Everyone learns this, nobody is born with the knowledge. :)