# Save the face detected in a png/jpg file

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save the face and eye detected using opencv in a separate png/jpg file, what can I use to do it.(I would want the rectangle as well). The code is as below: (I do not have GUI enabled)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/i855838/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/i855838/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('/Users/i855838/Desktop/xfiles4.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38045473/1874627

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `cv2.imwrite`. For example, to save to a file called 'face_color.png' you would do `cv2.imwrite('face_color.png', roi_color)`.