# How do I imshow, imwrite, print screen an image in Java OpenCV 3.4.O?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

In OpenCV 2.XX, images were displayed with

> HighGui.imshow(windowName, Mat image);

In OpenCV 3.XX the command is

> Imgcodecs.imwrite(windowName, Mat image);

But, It does not seem to work.  A short program follows ...

```
package myfirstPackage;

import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class ShowImage {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Load the native library.
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            Mat src = new Mat();
            src = Imgcodecs.imread("lena.jpg", Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
            Imgcodecs.imwrite( "lena.jpg", src );
            System.out.println("1/27/2018");
            }
}
```

Edit:

Migrating from OpenCV 2.x to 3.0.0 (Java)

Highgui.imread(fileName, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
Highgui.imread(fileName)
become resp:

Imgcodecs.imread(fileName, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
Imgcodecs.imread(fileName)
Also, drawing functions such as:

Core.circle(..), Core.line(..), etc..
Have been moved to:

Imgproc.circle(..), Imgproc.line(..)

Reference:
[HighGUI is missing from OpenCV 3.0.0 JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059576/highgui-is-missing-from-opencv-3-0-0-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059576/highgui-is-missing-from-opencv-3-0-0-jar); long story short, highgui was removed from OpenCV 3.X+.